# How to skip specification of the generic type parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

This is the main body of my function

```
val client = ConnectionFactory.createClient()  # <- Return lettice.io RedisClusterClient
val conn = client.connect()
val command = conn.sync()

var index: String? = null

index = readDataStructure(command, key)
```

This is my first try to define my `readDataStructure` function:

```
fun readDataStructure(command: RedisCommand, key: String): String {
 ...
```

kotlin complaints **`error: 3 type arguments expected for interface RedisCommand<K : Any!, V : Any!, T : Any!>`**

I want to be able to NOT specifying K, V and T because I am just writing a throwaway script.

Is there any Kotlin lang syntax and can allow me to just pass the `command` variable as is?

Comment: You can use `RedisCommand<*, *, *>` but if you are calling any methods on it that need to know the types, then you'll have to specify those types. I'd have to see the RedisCommand docs to explain any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are after:

```
fun readDataStructure(command: RedisCommand<*,*,*>, key: String): String {
```

?

From Kotlin docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/generics.html:

> If you don't have any idea (or don't care) what the generic type might be, you can use a star-projection:
>
> ```
> fun printSize(items: List<*>) = println(items.size)
> ```
>
> When using a generic type where you have star-projected one or more of its type parameters, you can:
>
> - Use any members that don't mention the star-projected type parameter(s) at all
> - Use any members that return the star-projected type parameter(s), but the return type will appear to be Any? (unless the type parameter is constrained, in which case you'll get the type mentioned in the constraint)
> - Not use any members that take a star-projected type as a parameter